# Azure: Authorization fail when trying to create notification hub namesapce

Tags: node.js, azure

Am using the node.js SDK to call the Azure notification hub api, I registered an application using Azure Active directory also i created a resource group and added my user to it as owner. But am getting this error when calling the api:

AuthorizationFailed

> The client '333848ca-f996-XXXXXXXXXXXX' with object id
>   '333848ca-f996-XXXXXXXXX' does not have authorization to perform
>   action 'Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/write' over scope
>   '/subscriptions/ef8e8e-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/notificationGroup/providers/Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/namespaceapp1

The code:

```
  MsRest.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(
    My Subscription ID,
    My Application Secret Key,
    My Directory ID, // found under AD -> properties 
    (err, credentials) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      // eslint-disable-next-line 
      const client = new notificationHubsClient(credentials, AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID);
      const createNamespaceParameters = {
        location: AZURE_LOCATION,
        tags: {
          tag1: 'value1',
          tag2: 'value2',
        },
      };
      client.namespaces.createOrUpdate(AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, req.body.name, createNamespaceParameters,
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            res.send(error);
          }
          console.info(`Namespace created${JSON.stringify(result, null, ' ')}`);
          res.send('app created');
        });
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you'll need to add your Azure Active directory application to the **Contributor** role for creating the namespace in Azure Notification Hub.

[image]

---

You can follow the steps below which are also documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role).

1. Go to [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com) and select **Subscriptions**.

[image]

2. Select the particular subscription (resource group or resource) to assign the application to.

[image]

3. Select **Access Control (IAM)**.

[image]

4. Select **Add**.

[image]

5. Select the **Contributor** role to assign to your AAD application.

[image]

Comment: My user is added as contributor to the subscription and to the resource group the subscription and the resource group has full access on notification hub, however i noticed there is no users assigned to the app owner when i tried to add my user it was un clickable even though it's the user that own the account .